# Changing audio source for media player (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create a button that plays a sound at random from the list of sounds on click. The code I have randomises the first sound, but the subsequent clicks do not trigger any sound. Do I have to release codec after the sound plays?

```
meow.setOnClickListener((view) ->{
            Random random = new Random();
            int r = random.nextInt(6-1) + 1;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Integer.valueOf(r).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try{
                if(r==1)
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat1);
                else if (r==2)
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat2);
                else if (r==3)
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat3);
                else if (r==4)
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat4);
                else
                    fileDescriptor = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.meowcat5);
                mp.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), fileDescriptor.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check state of player, pause/stop if is active and call `mp.release();` before loading next song into

with second and further clicks you have probably some `Exception` log produced by `e.printStackTrace();`, check it out, will tell you what is wrong

also make use of [create](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#create(android.content.Context,%2520android.net.Uri,%2520android.view.SurfaceHolder)) method, which will load your `R.raw` file and return **new** instance of `MediaPlayer`. before doing that release previous player instance if exists

```
if (mp!=null) mp.release(); // maybe needs also a  check if playing and stop before?
mp = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(), R.raw.meowcat100);
mp.start(); // dont have to call prepare in this case
```

Answer (score 1):

call `mp.reset()` before setting new data source